# Can we make a phase space plot for any quantum mechanical system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, phase-space

Can we make a phase space plot for any quantum mechanical system? If we can then lets say at a particular point represented by $(q,p)$ does not it violate the Heisenberg Uncertainity as we simultaneously measure the momentum and position.

Answer (score 2):

You can never locate a particle at one point in phase space, as that would violate the uncertainty principle. You could plot the *expected value* of $q$ and $p$ in time, but you would clearly be missing a lot of information about the wave function.

There are some [phase space formulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation) of quantum mechanics, which use [quasi-probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution) on phase space (which are like probability distributions, but can be negative), like the [Wigner distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) or the [Glauber-Sudarashan P representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glauber%E2%80%93Sudarshan_P_representation).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make phase space plots in quantum mechanics, but they are not based on the usual Schrödinger wavefunctions $\psi(x)$ or $\phi(p)$, both of which depend on only one variable.  Rather, Wigner functions, which for $x$ and $p$ are obtained as
\begin{align}
W(x,p)=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy e^{-ipy/\hbar} \psi(x+\textstyle\frac{1}{2}y)\psi^* (x-\frac{1}{2}y)
\end{align}
and play the role of a phase space *distribution*, in the sense that average values are phase space integrals of the variable multiplied by the probability distribution $W(x,p)$.  Thus for instance
\begin{align}
\langle x\rangle &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx dp \,x \, W(x,p)\, , \\
\langle p\rangle &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx dp \, p\, W(x,p)\, .
\end{align}

Nothing in this violates the uncertainty principle as one can show that it is not possible for the Wigner function be arbitrarily sharply peaked, meaning it's not possible to have a WF that have very sharply defined position *and* momentum.  Indeed, as discussed  [near Eq.(23) of this paper](http://www.stat.physik.uni-potsdam.de/%7Epikovsky/teaching/stud_seminar/Wigner_function.pdf)
the maximum amplitude of the WF at a point satisfies
\begin{align}
\vert W(x,p)\vert\le 2/\hbar\, .
\end{align}

The Wigner function for the ground state of the harmonic oscillator is given below.

[image]

One of the most intriguing part of this approach is that Wigner functions can have regions where they are negative, *i.e.* parts of the probability *distribution* is negative.   For instance the Wigner function of the $n=1$ state of the harmonic oscillator yields

[image]

This has been verified experimentally by [David Wineland and his group](https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=104995) in

> Leibfried, Dietrich, D. M. Meekhof, B. E. King, C. H. Monroe, Wayne M. Itano, and David J. Wineland. "Experimental determination of the motional quantum state of a trapped atom." *Physical Review Letters* 77, no. 21 (1996): 4281.

The figure below is extracted from this paper, where parts of the region of negative probability density are very apparent.

[image]

The negative regions in the Wigner functions are a considerable source of discussion.  In particular it has been argued in

> Kenfack, A. and Życzkowski, K., 2004. Negativity of the Wigner function as an indicator of non-classicality. *Journal of Optics B: Quantum and Semiclassical Optics*, *6*(10), p.396.

that are tied to non-classical features of the associated quantum states.